# problem running code in VS code using scanf

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

concern! I was setting up Vs code for the first time and  I used scanf for taking input from users.but it shows something like that "cannot open output file test.exe: Permis/../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file test.exe: Pesion denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5zHd.png)

Comment: Better to post you code here.

Answer (score 0):

You have your exe file locked by another process. Exit VS and then delete manually the .exe file

To avoid similar problems set the directory permissions correctly (you need to have full access) and always terminate the debug session (or running program) before next build.